# Julia: Transform Row vector to column Vector

Tags: julia

How do I transform a row vector like the one above (`1x3`)

```
a = [1 2 3];
```

In to a column vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! It's `vec()`. The reason why I couldn't find it is because I kept on looking for "row vector". Instead it's a 2D array.

Simply use `vec(a)` and it will be a standard column vector.

Comment: note that `vec` is non alocating so you are actually getting pointer to the same data just with it's dimension dropeed.

Comment: If you don't want to loose the 2D form of the Array you can use also `transpose(a)`

Comment: or the shorthand notation of the adjoint `a'`. Notice the single quotation mark and that this flips the sign of imaginary values.